# VBA IF formula not working?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, formula

I have some VBA code that is working between a few workbooks

I am running into a problem where I cannot get this IF formula to apply.
I am not sure how I am getting `Subscript out of range` error.

I have tried to use `.Range("O")`, `.Range("O:O")`, `.Range("O", i)` but all give the same 1004 error.

Am I using .Range() wrong? I was able to use range on a different formula so not sure why this wont work.

```
Sub if_after()

    Dim co_detail As Workbook
    Set co_detail = ThisWorkbook

        With co_detail.Sheets("Detail")

            For i = 2 To 100
                .Range("O2").Formula = "=IF(L" & i & "=N" & i & ",'good','update')"
            Next i

        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("02")` should perhaps be `Range("O2")` (the letter 'O' instead of a zero)

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad that was just a type here. Thanks for pointing it out. My original code uses O.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a zero not an oh and full quotes are used for text. Quotes must also be doubled up within a quoted string.

```
.Range("o" & i).Formula = "=IF(L" & i & "=N" & i & ", ""good"", ""update"")"
```

Comment: The 0 in my question was a typo sorry. Looks like I am wrong about the single quotes. Thanks for the fix on that.

Comment: I am actually using some single quotes inside of one of my formulas and it is working however I don't think it is used as a quote but rather part of the file path.

Comment: Yes, something like a worksheet name with one or more spaces must be enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify this entire code to the following - no need to loop at all, you can just `Resize`:

```
Sub If_after()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Detail").Range("O2").Resize(99).Formula = "=IF(L2=N2,""good"",""update"")"
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes thank you I did actually do that one already. Once I had the `For` loop figured out I was able to go back to the other way that didn't use a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.Range("o" & i).Formula = …` try using `.Range("o" & i).FormulaR1C1 …`. I always use `FormulaR1C1` instead of `Formula`.

Comment: I was reading on FormulaR1C1 but I do not see any clear advantage.

Comment: And an xlA1 reference like C3 would be misinterpreted as C:C in xlR1C1.

Comment: @Jeeped, thanks for the tip. I'll keep this in mind.